# What should I be doing to secure my web form UI?

Tags: security, validation, forms

I have a mostly desktop programming background.  In my spare time I dabble in web development, page faulting my way from problem to solution with some success.  I have reached the point were I need to allow site logins and collect some data from a community of users (that is the plan anyway).

So, I realize there is a whole world of nefarious users out there who are waiting eagerly for an unsecured site to decorate, vandalize and compromise.  If I am really lucky, a couple of those users might make their way to my site.  I would like to be reasonably prepared for them.

I have a UI to collect information from a logged in user and some of that information is rendered into HTML pages.  My site is implemented with PHP/MySQL on the back end and some javascript stuff on the front.  I am interested in any suggestions/advice on how I should tackle any of the following issues:

- Cross Site Scripting : I am hoping this will be reasonably simple for me since I am not supporting marked down input, just plain text.  Should I be just scanning for [A-Za-z ]* and throwing everything else out?  I am pretty ignorant about the types of attacks that can be used here, so I would love to hear your advice.
- SQL injection : I am using parametized queries (mysqli) here , so I am hoping I am OK in this department.  Is there any extra validation I should be doing on the user entered data to protect myself?
- Trollish behaviour : I am supporting polylines drawn by the user on a Google Map, so (again if I am lucky enough to get some traffic)  I expect to  see a few hand drawn phallices scrawled across western Europe.  I am planning to implement some user driven moderation (flag inaproriate SO style), but I would be interested in any other suggestions for discouraging this kind of behavior.
- Logins : My [current login system](http://www.cannonade.net/ww2) is a pretty simple web form, MySQL query in PHP, mp5 encoded password validation, and a stored session cookie.  I hope the system is simple enough to be secure, but I wonder if their are vulnerabilies here I am not aware of?

I hope I haven't been too verbose here and look forward to hearing your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross Site Scripting can be easily taken care of with htmlentities, there is also a function called strip tags which removes the tags from the post and you'll note that this allows you to whitelist certain tags. If you do decide to allow specific tags through in the future keep in mind that the attributes on these tags are not cleaned in any way, this can be used to insert javascript in the page (onClick etc.) and is not really recommended. If you want to have formatting in the future I'd recommend implementing a formatting language (like [b] for bold or something similar) to stop your users from just entering straight html into the page.

SQL Injection is also easily taken care of as you can prepare statements and then pass through the user data as arguments to the prepared statement. This will stop any user input from modifying the sql statement.

CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) is an often overlooked vulnerability that allows an attacker to submit data from a victims account using the form. This is usually done either by specifying your form get string for an img src (the image loads for the victim, the get loads and the form is processed, but the user is unaware ). Additionally if you use post the attacker can use javascript to auto-submit a hidden form to do the same thing as above. To solve this one you need to generate a key for each form, keep one in the session and one on the form itself (as a hidden input). When the form is submitted you compare the key from the input with the key in the session and only continue if they match.

Some security companies also recommend that you use the attribute 'autocomplete="off"' on login forms so the password isn't saved.

Comment: Looks like strip_tags is what I am looking for.  I doubt that I will be implementing any fancy formatting in the data I am consuming, but thanks for the overview on that stuff. I will also have a look at handling the CSRF case, looks pretty straightforward. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you are concerned with your UI. A simple rule to follow is that you should never assume the submitted data is coming from a UI that you created. Don't trust the data coming in, and sanitize the data going out. Use PHP's strip_tags and/or htmlentities.

Certain characters (<,>,",') can screw up your HTML and permit injection, but should be allowed. Especially in passwords. Use htmlentities to permit the use of these characters. Just think about what would happen if certain characters were output without being "escaped".

Javascript based checks and validation should only be used to improve the user experience (i.e. prevent a page reload). Do not use eval except as an absolute last resort.

Comment: I probably should have been clearer, this validation is being done on the server in PHP, no assumptions about where the submit is coming from.  Nice point thought :).

Comment: use htmlspecialchars instead of htmlentities if you work with multi byte charset.

Answer (score 1):

Against XSS htmlspecialchars is pretty enough, use it to clear the output. 
SQL injection: if mysql parses your query before adds the parameters, afaik its not possible to inject anything malicious.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into something else besides only allowing [A-Za-z]* into your page.  Just because you have no intention of allowing any formatting markup now doesn't mean you won't have a need for it down the line.  Personally I hate rewriting things that I didn't design to adapt to future needs.

You might want to put together a whitelist of accepted tags, and add/remove from that as necessary, or look into encoding any markup submitted into plain text.